# Still getting "cannot Connect to iTunes" for in-app purchase

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, sandbox

Comments in the SKPaymentQueue.h seem to indicate that the "USER will be asked to authenticate" if it is a restoreCompletedTransactions. It does not indicate authentication for addPayment. So, at what point is the login window supposed to pop up during a purchase? I get a login when I use my "restore" process, but keep getting the dreaded "cannot connect" error when I try to purchase. No pop up for authentications.

What exactly happens when I call "addPayment"?

I receive a transaction in the payment Queue almost immediately with the Cannot Connect error when I do the addPayment.

Products are correct, bundleID is correct, have done 6 test users, wiped phone, tried not signing in, signing in.

also tried all the tricks in the other "cannot connect" questions.

Is there a question in this area I missed?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using a product ID from the wrong area in iTunes connect.